# Nest.js Transaction interceptor

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs, interceptor

I'm having interceptor for mongoose transactions like below

I have a dependency on mongoose connection from
`import Connection from 'mongoose'`
I have injected that using `InjectConnection` decorator.

Now I want to set this interceptor globally.

I'm writing it like.
`app.useGlobalInterceptors(new MyInterceptor()).`

It gives me an error to pass connection dependency from MyInterceptor.
Thanks

Comment: What error u get?

Comment: please add  the actual code and error, your question is not clear :) you are just describing your problem and it can be hard to understand, imagine you're showing your code to someone in person.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: MyInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Sorry, don't forget to import 
```import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';```

Comment: My interceptor is outside of any modules in a separate interceptors folder and I can write this above code in any module, is that correct?

Comment: @ks9 if I'm having the right image here in my head about how everything is set up, then yes, you should be able to add this in any module code, but this should be added specifically in the modules where the integration with mongoose is required